# Turning RData file into script files

Tags: r, rdata

Is there a straightforward way to turn the functions of a .RData file into a normal code file (.R)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out `?dump`.  For example:

```
newEnv <- new.env()
load("myFunctions.Rdata", newEnv)
dump(c(lsf.str(newEnv)), file="normalCodeFile.R", envir=newEnv)
```

You may also be interested in `?prompt` (which creates documentation files for objects) and / or `?package.skeleton`.

Comment: Great update Joshua.  I updated my post to include your solution as well. http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/09/dumping-functions-from-the-global-environment-into-an-r-script-file/

Answer (score 3):

This recent blog post addresses a basically the same problem:

http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/09/dumping-functions-from-the-global-environment-into-an-r-script-file/

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11986821/3798912) using `sink`

```
sink(file="Function.R")
Function # The object
sink()
```