# How to save a function as new R script?

Tags: r, function, save

Given a function, how to save it to an R script (.R)?

Save works well with data, but apparently can not create .R data.

Copy pasting from the console to a new script file appears to introduce characters that cause errors.

Comment: Related: [Turning RData file into script files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835714/r-turning-rdata-file-into-script-files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the `dump` function.  That writes files that are `R` code that can be read back in with `source` or used in some other way.

Comment: Is there a way to get the name space/environment specified with the function to also be dumped to the R file?  If I want to edit a function from a package but still have this new function access the same name space as its original?

Comment: I don't believe there is. You would have to call `assignInNamespace` for that.

Answer (score 3):

I have to ask:  why are you writing your functions in the console in the first place?  Any number of editors support a "source" call, so you can update the function as you edit.  Copy/pasting from the console will carry prompt characters along , if nothing else, so it's a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: Found myself doing this 'at the console stuff' while noodling around with some useful seqle (cgwTools pkg) functions and didn't want to lose the insights.